# Joining 2 tables and getting sum of coincidences

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

Table from registered users:

- id_user
- id_location
- name

Table from locations:

- id_location
- name

I need to know how many users there are in each location. Something like this:

- Washington: 455
- Florida: 185
- Texas: 914

It tried with this approach but the results have definitely sum errors.

```
SELECT location.name,user.id_user FROM user
INNER JOIN location ON user.id_location = location.id_location
WHERE user.id_profile !=0 GROUP BY location.id_location ORDER BY location.name
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you did not provide some sort of aggregate function to your data.  You are just returning the location name and the user id.  How would you from your query get the user count?  You need to apply `COUNT` and wrap that around your user_id field as well as group by the location.

Comment: @JonH thanks for the notice! Haven't slept all night, completely missed that part :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close, you just need to do a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT location.name, COUNT(user.id_user) UserCount 
FROM user
INNER JOIN location 
ON user.id_location = location.id_location
WHERE user.id_profile !=0 
GROUP BY location.name
ORDER BY location.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT location.id_location, location.name, COUNT(user.id_user) AS UserCount
FROM user 
INNER JOIN location ON user.id_location = location.id_location 
WHERE user.id_profile !=0 
GROUP BY location.id_location, location.name
ORDER BY location.name
```

I've added the `id_location` to the query in case you somehow have the same Location Name, but different location IDs.